# Series resistor selection using B value

Tags: thermistor

I am following [this document](https://shadyelectronics.com/accurate-temperature-measurement-using-an-ntc-thermistor-with-an-arduino-or-stm32-microcontroller/) to calculate the series resistor for an NTC.

Here the NTC used is [NTCG164LH223HT1](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/sensor/ntc/chip-ntc-thermistor/catalog/tpd_commercial_ntc-thermistor_ntcg_en.pdf).Below is the snippet from the calculation section.

[image]

In the equation for **RNTC** the B value is taken as 4503.67.Please see below.The datasheet value of B is 4550.

[image]

1. May I know how they arrived the value of B as 4503.67?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [TDK website](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/sensor/ntc/chip-ntc-thermistor/list#part_no=NTCG164LH223HT1&_l=20&_p=1&_c=5r25-5r25&_d=0), we download the .csv file for this particular thermistor and find the **nominal** resistance at 0°C and 100°C - 83.71kΩ and 1.009kΩ respectively.

The author then calculates \$\beta\$ for the range 0°C/100°C to  from the equation:

\$\beta = \ln(R_{T1}/R_{T2})\cdot (1/T1-1/T2)^{-1} \$

The author rounds the right-hand term to 1019.3 rather than the exact answer of  1019.259225 and calculates the result (rounded to two decimal places)  as

\$\beta\$ = 4503.67

Without that intermediate rounding the result would be 4503.49 rounded to two decimal places.

Note that \$\beta\$ has a tolerance of +/-3% for this relatively poor precision thermistor so the discrepancy is irrelevant.

---

The geometric mean method the author uses for the series resistor is one solution if you know nothing about the actual application, however if you know that the thermistor is to be used at some specific temperature you may prefer to have the series resistor equal to the thermistor resistance at that temperature. That will maximize the resolution at that temperature. For example, for a room temperature thermostat you may wish to have it indicate over a wide range, but you expect most users will set it in the range (say) 22°C +/-5°C.

Another factor which should be considered is self-heating which may point to using a higher value resistor than would otherwise seem optimal.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the article, the B coefficient for \$0 ^\circ C \$ and \$100 ^\circ C \$ is not available and the writer derived from this equation:
$$ B = \frac{T_1 \cdot T_2}{T_2-T_1} \cdot ln (\frac{R_1}{R_2})$$

\$ T_1 = 273.15K\$

\$ T_2 = 373.15K\$

\$ R_1 = 83.71kΩ\$

\$ R_2 = 1.009kΩ\$

Therefore,
$$ B = \frac{273.15K \cdot 373.15K }{373.15K-273.15K} \cdot ln (\frac{83.71kΩ}{1.009kΩ})$$
$$ B = 4503.49363807$$

Comment: The value of R1 and R2 is calculated using B value only.Please see the equation for Rmin and Rmax.

Comment: In the article stated that "The B value is specified across a given temperature range and represents the change in resistance of the thermistor across that specified temperature range". The author also said that in order to make the calculation complete, they need B(0/100) and meanwhile the datasheet provide B(25/85).

Comment: In previous section, the author said that the manufacturer provide resistance data at 0 centigrade and 100 centigrade. From that data, I assume the author use same data to calculate the B value for R_min and R_max calculation.

Comment: You are backcalculating B from Rmin and Rmax